# Expo Segment Anonymous Id

Tags: expo, analytics, segment

Is it possible to reach the anonymous id like in the client version with `analytics.user().anonymousId()` in expo ?

I have tried the node version and it seems there is missing

Answer (score 0):

`analytics._user.anonymousId()` will spit out the anonymous id set by Segment